# Port a line of code from earlier version of Mathematica to version 8

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a an old line of code from Mathematica version 6 or 7 that I need to port to Mathematica 8.

I don't have a working version of 6 or 7 so I can't run the original code to do a side by side test to see if I get the same results.  I thought someone here might know just from looking at the code.

Earlier version:

```
Regress[data, x, x, RegressionReport -> {FitResiduals}][[1]][[2]]
```

I've tried the following in version 8:

```
LinearModelFit[data, x, x]["FitResiduals"]
```

I have no way to tell if the new code will give me either the output and/or the format of the output of the earlier version.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks to all for making this such a great resource!

J.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the output of this code from Version 6:

```
FitResiduals /.  Regress[data, x, x, RegressionReport -> {FitResiduals}]
```

... is indeed equivalent to this code from Version 8:

```
LinearModelFit[data, x, x]["FitResiduals"]
```

... for the sets of random reals I tried. The difference between the two results is effectively zero:

```
In[26]:= fromV6 == fromV8

Out[26]= True

In[27]:= fromV6 - fromV8

Out[27]= {0., 1.11022*10^-16, 0., 0., 1.11022*10^-16}
```

`Regress` returns a list of rules, and the `[[1]][[2]]` business extracts the RHS of the first rule. The method I used above (`FitResiduals /. Regress[...]`) is a better way to do that.

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [upgrade tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Compatibility/tutorial/Statistics/LinearRegression.html) for the old statistics module, `Regress` was last seen in version 6. Based on the fact that "FitResiduals" is not in the list of renamed properties at the bottom of the page, I would say that the output of your new version should be pretty close to the old version.

If you want somebody to test for you, I would suggest putting up a small working dataset and post the output from the new code -- then somebody will probably post the output from v5 or v6. The documentation for the old module is [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Add-onsLinks/StandardPackages/Statistics/LinearRegression.html).

HTH